# How to display a DIV only when the page is visited in the second time in react

Tags: reactjs

I am new in React and I want a specific div to be shown in the second time a user visits the page, how could I do it? Does any help please?

Comment: "he second time a user visits the page" can actually mean several things in a client-server context. Could you please be more precise about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Well I have file in the public folder which is created every time I click on a button, the problem is, that because the file is in the public folder the page refresh every time it is created. So for the first time the user visit the page he still didn't click on the button I don't want to get the old file already exists in the public folder, but when he clicks he will get the new file as he requested.. I hope you get it

Comment: Sorry, your problem is still too vague for me to help. May I suggest you to create a minimal reproducible example on codesandbox.io ?